# Understanding syntax for navigation using JS Angular + HTML (ng-click="save(userForm)".....)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to understand what part of this syntax is doing. I've been looking for tutorials an I can't find this.

There are two separated lines that I don't know what they do:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(userForm)"
        ng-hide="nav.autofilled">
  {{(nav.requireEdge || obj.connector || obj.current.anchor) ? '(Next)' : '(Save)'}}
</button>
```

More specifically, this part:

```
ng-hide="nav.autofilled">

{{(nav.requireEdge || obj.connector || obj.current.anchor) ? '(Next)' : '(Save)'}}
```

Could you explain me what it does or where can I find a tutorial about this, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

That part is just checking if any of the three expressions has truthy values and setting the text in the button.

If any of three expressions `nav.requireEdge, obj.connector or obj.current.anchor` has truthy value i.e. anything other than `null, undefined, 0, false or empty string(''/"")`, the button will have text (Next). Else the button will have text (Save)

Comment: Empty strings `""`,`''`,`\`\`` are also [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 0):

In your codes

`ng-click="save(userForm)"` indicates that in the component after click which event should call

`ng-hide="nav.autofilled"` said if `nav.autfilled` is true then add class hide to the element

and with this condition `{{(nav.requireEdge || obj.connector || obj.current.anchor) ? '(Next)' : '(Save)'}}` the button caption is set dynamically with `(Next)` or `(Save)`

AngularJs easy to understand, this is an example you can looking for it

[AngularJS Events: ng-click, ng-show, ng-hide](https://www.guru99.com/angularjs-events.html)